# pass variable to angularjs directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass variable to directive

```
app.directive('pagination',function () {
    //custom directive for build pagination
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        template:function (elem,attr) 
            //not getting the value 
            console.log(attr.pageCount);
        }
    };
})
```

in my html

```
<pagination page-count="pageCount" ></pagination>
```

but the `pageCount` value is not getting inside the `template` but `page-count=2` this will give the value inside the template

**UPDATE**

```
 <% var i = 1;
            if (currentPage > 5) {
                i = +currentPage - 4;
            } %>
        <% for (i; i<=pageCount; i++) { %>
        <% if (currentPage == i) { %>
        <li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link"><%= i %></a></li>
        <% } else { %>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=<%= i %>"><%= i %></a></li>
        <% } %>
        <% if (i == (+currentPage + 4)) { %>
        <% break; } %>
        <% } %>
```

I want to equivalent HTML in angularjs

`currentPage`  and `pageCount` values can be get from the controller

**UPDATE AGAIN**

Now i can able to get the values in `link`

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pagecount: '=',
            currentpage: '='
        },
        template:function (elem,attr) {
           return 'hello';
        },
        link:function (scope,elem,attr) {
            console.log("count",scope.pagecount,scope.currentpage);
        }
    };
```

But how can i dynamically build the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the value from the scope by couple of way.

1. Using `scope: {}` isolated scope, and use that binding on page directly. You can't directly get scope bindings inside `template` function.

   ```
   app.directive('pagination',function ($compile) { //<- inject $compile
     //custom directive for build pagination
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       template: '<div>{{pageCount}}</div>'
       scope: {
          pageCount: '='//or use  `>` if it is Angular 1.5.3+
       },
       link: function (scope,elem) {
          //get scope.pageCount value and create template based on it. And append to body
          var template = 'myTemplateInStringFormat';
          element.append($compile(template)(scope));
       }
     };
   })
   ```
2. Evaluate value from the current scope. using `$eval`/`$parse` inside the link function of directive. Like `$scope.$eval('pageCount');`

Comment: Actullay i want variable inside `template:function (elem,attr){} ` bcz i want to build some dynamic HTML content based on that value

Comment: @Jabaa can you please elaborate, what exactly you wanna create as a custom HTML?

Comment: I just want to print 
        `for (i; i<=pageCount; i++) {//<li></l> here}`

Comment: @Jabaa that can be easily achievable with the help of `ng-repeat` rather than generating template from template function

Comment: But there is some calculation is required to value of `i` so i can't use ng-repeat in it

Comment: @Jabaa please brief your problem.. Also if you can add plunker/jsfiddle. then that would be awesome. I can jump in to help you out

Comment: does `<%` & `%>` is interpolation, or you're using different template engine?

Comment: Its ejs template engine

Comment: i am little bit closer to the answer please go through with my updated question